# Why do these error occur (Unity Input System)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A few minutes back I upgraded/updated the Input System package via the Package Manager to version 1.4.2 (from version 1.4.1). Now after every time I enter play mode and exit, I get the same error message **SIX TIMES** in the Unity Editor:

```
Type of instance in array does not match expected type
UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput:OnDisable () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4.2/InputSystem/Plugins/PlayerInput/PlayerInput.cs:1734)
```

But I don't know why this error occurs or even why it shows up, **but I want to FIX it**. Must I report it to Unity or what?

Comment: Did you do a clean build in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new bug introduced on Input System 1.4.1+ when using multiple control schemas in the InputActions.

The new 2021.3.8f1 LTS will force update the Input System to 1.4.1.

As of 1.4.2, the bug is still there. This seems to be going for a month and no fixes yet.

If you can, downgrade it to 1.3.0 until this gets a bugfix update.

**To manually downgrade the package:**

- Close the project.
- Open Packages\Manifest.json and change the input package to "com.unity.inputsystem": "1.3.0".
- Then just to be sure you can also delete the old version Library\PackageCache\com.unity.inputsystem@1.4.2
- Reopen the project and you should now have the working version.

You can also follow some other discussion threads about this issue:

- https://forum.unity.com/threads/errors-with-new-input-system-when-exiting-play-mode-solved.632644/
- https://forum.unity.com/threads/in-14456-exceptions-after-upgrading-input-system-to-1-4-2.1324083/